# How to call some global variable from forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm making a loop for getting data using forEach on `NodeJS`

```
var detail = await orderModels.get_rab_workitem_v2(order_id)
        detail.forEach(keys => {
                var beneficiary_name = keys.cp_name
                var beneficiary_account = keys.bank_account_number
                var beneficiary_bank = keys.iris_code
                var beneficiary_email = keys.email
        })
```

the question is, how to call `beneficiary_name` variable from inside of forEach loops `NodeJS`?

I mean i want to call `beneficiary_name` variable outside the forEach loops, Like :

```
var detail = await orderModels.get_rab_workitem_v2(order_id)
            detail.forEach(keys => {
                    var beneficiary_name = keys.cp_name
                    var beneficiary_account = keys.bank_account_number
                    var beneficiary_bank = keys.iris_code
                    var beneficiary_email = keys.email
            })
var test = beneficiary_name
```

how?

Comment: Do you want to get `beneficiary_name ` on each iteration?

Comment: What would you expect `beneficiary_name` to be? If it was scoped outside the loop, it would just be the final `keys.cp_name` set on the final iteration?

Comment: i mean, i want to get beneficiary_name and use for all like global variable

Comment: i've been updated the question, i hope u understand.

Comment: I'd suggest you read this article on [variable-scoping in javascript](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

Comment: If you try the above way only the last value will be set in beneficiary_name, i.e. last keys's cp_name

Comment: Declare `beneficiary_xxx` before your loop. But be aware that all `beneficiary_xxx` variables will have only the last iteration values.

Comment: yes, how if i want to get the value (beneficiary_name) outside the each loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring your Variables outside the loop and then setting them within the loop will allow your `test` Var to reference the beneficiary variables... your loop however will set the beneficiary variables to the last element in the detail array. If you are planning on doing something with each beneficiary variable upon each iteration of the `detail` Array, i suggest you do that logic within your loop - not outside because of the above point.

```js
var beneficiary_name
var beneficiary_account
var beneficiary_bank
var beneficiary_email

var detail = await orderModels.get_rab_workitem_v2(order_id)
detail.forEach(keys => {
        beneficiary_name = keys.cp_name
        beneficiary_account = keys.bank_account_number
        beneficiary_bank = keys.iris_code
        beneficiary_email = keys.email
})

var test = beneficiary_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems like you want to get the last assigned value to `beneficiary_name`.

So basically you can skip the `forEach` and just read the value from the last index:

```
var detail = await orderModels.get_rab_workitem_v2(order_id);
var test = detail[detail.length - 1].cp_name;
```

But in case you want an array of key.cp_name you can either use `detail.map(keys => keys.cp_name)` or you can define an array in the correct scope and push your data:

```
var beneficiary_name_list = [];
var detail = await orderModels.get_rab_workitem_v2(order_id)
            detail.forEach(keys => {
                    var beneficiary_name = keys.cp_name
                    var beneficiary_account = keys.bank_account_number
                    var beneficiary_bank = keys.iris_code
                    var beneficiary_email = keys.email

                    beneficiary_name_list.push(keys.cp_name);
            })
var test = beneficiary_name_list
```